# Jenkins S3 plugin unable to delete files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins Setup works as follows:

1. Takes checkout of code from Github
2. Publishes the code successfully to my S3 bucket.

The IAM user I have configured for it has full access permission to S3.

But the problem occurs if I delete a file/directory, it updates all the files in my s3 bucket but doesn't removes the deleted files/directories. Is Deleting files/directories not possible by Jenkins S3 plugin?

Answer (score 1):

S3 plugin removes files on `onDelete` event. Jenkins creates this event when it goes to remove build from history (due to rotation or something like that). Uploading works only as **uploading** - not **updating**.